# why "next planet" and why "over" in "NASA has said it plans to send humans to the next planet over by 2030"?

Tags: comprehension

Source: [NASA on Eve of Big Announcement: 'Mars Mystery Solved'](http://www.esquire.com/news-politics/a38289/nasa-mars-mystery-solved/)

Example:

> The agency's most advanced Martian explorer, the Curiosity rover, has
>   been milling slowly about a tiny tract of the Red Planet since
>   mid-2012, beaming back unprecedented photos and data that have
>   captivated public attention.
>   NASA has said it plans to **send humans to the next planet over** by 2030. Whatever the agency reveals on Monday seems likely to become a key detail in its ongoing mission to Mars.

First of all, I don't understand what they mean by *the next planet*. Obviously, they're talking about Mars, but why are they referring to it as the second planet to send humans to? Was there ever a first planet? I though the moon was a satellite. Secondly, do we really need the preposition *over* there? Is it equally alright to say *send humans to the next planet by 2030*?

Comment: **[send over](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/send%20over)** --  to dispatch across the sea, through the air, or from one place to another

Comment: It's not "send over". It is "send someone to someplace over".

Comment: I think you can read this "over" as "again". (Not very sure because I haven't read the text.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Over* is not strictly necessary; but it is not merely colloquial amplification. It also serves to disambiguate *next*.

> NASA plans to send humans to the next planet in 2030.

This might be taken in a chronological sense: the planet to which we will next send humans. *Over* tells us that *next* is understood in a spatial sense: the next planet in line, the nearest planet.

Comment: "NASA has said it plans to send humans **over** to the next planet by 2030." -- I wonder if **over** would lose its disambiguating role if we position it in this more natural way.

Comment: @CopperKettle No, that won't do. There *over* heads a locative complement. In the original *next X over* works like *next X in line* or *next X on the list*: *over* complements *next* and the construction modifies *X*